# Is there an audio player for Android which remembers my last position in a track?

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I'm looking for an audio player application which can remember where I've left the track.

**Example:**

1. I'm listening track A and at time 8:52 I pause the track.
2. Then I decide to listen track B. And at time 15:42 I stop the player.
3. Later I return back to track A, but instead of playing it from the start, I wan't to start where I've left before, i.e. at time 8:52.
4. Similarly for track B, I want it play from 15:42.

It is similar to an E-Book reader, which remembers on which page you've left for each book you're reading. So I would like to have same for audio files.

I would prefer a free app, but if is there a paid one (with reasonable price), I would go for it.

Comment: You can still play music with MX Player! It is disabled by default that it searches just videos. What u need to do is to go
- Settings/Audio/ -> Use as Audio Player Hope it helps :)

Comment: @SamoMobitel I think you were about to add this comment under the answer, not the quesion ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [MX Player for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en).
You can even start the audio from the first or resume it from the last time where you have stopped it.
It also works for video files.

Comment: I don't think it can play music anymore

Comment: The MX player DOES NOT remember position of .mp3 where you left them, at least not for Android. The accepted answer should be the Voice Audiobook Player. It's the only app in my experience that properly remembers position.

Comment: Agree.. MX does not remember MP3 position

Answer (score 3):

If you're listening to a series of audio (or video!) files like it's an audiobook, I recommend [Voice Audiobook Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ph1b.audiobook). In addition to remembering your playback position within one of the files in a folder, it's open source and ad-free, and has options to adjust the playback speed.

Comment: This does seem to be the most widely-used and well-reviewed open source audiobook player. The main other one I see is AudioAnchor, https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.prangesoftwaresolutions.audioanchor/

Comment: Great app. I've tried many apps on my Android, and this is the ONLY ONE that remembers position of files where you stopped listening to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this in order to listen to music or speech which you want to download manually then I don't know. But if you want this because you listen to podcasts and you're fine with downloading them via their RSS/Atom feeds, then I highly recommend the [Podcast & Radio Addict app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bambuna.podcastaddict&hl=en). It remembers your position in each podcast exactly the way you described, even shows the position as a small progress bar in the podcast list and provides tons of other features, such as the automatic download of the latest podcast episodes from RSS/Atom feeds that I mentioned (not restricted to podcasts that were set up to work with the app - any feed URL will do). It's free with ads or you can pay to remove the ads.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but still a valid answer. :-)

I've found that "Smart Audiobook Player" is almost perfect for my needs, all for just $2 !!!

There's not much is doesn't do with regards what you might want when listening to an audiobook... it will even sync your progress across devices, while keeping that information locally for safe-keeping!

HTH

> The app is designed specially for playing audio books.
> Assumed that you have audiobooks and already copied them to your phone.
> First 30 days Full version. Later - Basic version.
>
> Features:
>
> - Chromecast support.
> - Playback speed control.
> - Classification of books (new, started, finished).
> - Download cover from the Internet.
> - List of characters. You can manually create a list of characters to easier follow the story.
> - Automatic pause in case you fall asleep. To continue playback just shake your phone.
> - Playback history.
> - Application Widget. Allows you to control the player from the home screen.
> - By specifying a root folder containing all your audiobook, you can exclude your folders which contains music and other audio files.
> - You don't have to finish one book to start another.
> - The progress is saved independently for all books.
> - NO ADS!
>
> To purchase (restore after reinstalling) full version press:
> menu--Help--Version tab
> Phone must be connected to the Internet.
> Full version cost is $2.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: I think the question is asking for a music player that works as well as audio-book players, not about an audio-book player.